# Close modal when user clicks outside of it, why is there == and not !=?

Tags: javascript

I looked at some code from here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp, but I want to understand why is there == and not != in the folowing part of code:

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('yourModalId');

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

We want to close the window when the outside of the modal is clicked. Why is there an equal sign there than?

Comment: `modal` is the gray element filling the entire window except for the actual modal. It's named poorly; should probably be `overlay` or `modalBackdrop` something.

Comment: It's funny because their modal is the mask which can be misleading as it is in your case.

Comment: But the modal-content is inside of the modal so why doesn't it close when I click there?

Comment: Because the target is then `modal-content` rather than `modal`. Note that "[event.target] is different from [event.currentTarget] when the event handler is called during the bubbling or capturing phase of the event." See [event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it's because `modal` is the background, and `modal-content` is what you think should be the modal.

See the working example [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_modal), and notice this block of CSS:

```
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}
```

Comment: In future please don't try to copy paste CSS from w3school. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on the link provided, `modal` is the lightbox of the modal. (The transparent background) So when a user clicks that, close the modal.